# jQuery re-checking check boxes

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, push, checkbox

I having problems with re-checking some checkboxes after
and ajax call updates a table.

I have a table of what the project calls 'shares'.

I want to:

1) check for and save any checked shares to an array
2) Do my ajax call to update the table of shares
3) Re-check any there we checked before the ajax update.

My code is not working and I can't see why?

Any tips, help or advise much appreciated.

```
// Array to hold our checked share ids
var savedShareIDs = new Array();

// Add checked share ids into array
$("input:checkbox[name=share_ids]:checked").each(function() {  
 savedShareIDs.push($(this).val());  
});     

// Do ajax update
Dajaxice.pagination_shares('Dajax.process',{'id':1, 'page':1})

// Re-check any that were checked before ajax update
$("input:checkbox[name=share_ids]").each(function()  
{  
 if ( $.inArray( $(this).val(), savedShareIDs) > -1 ) {   
  $(this).attr('checked',true)  
 }  
});
```

The problem is the checkboxes are not checking.
I'm pretty sure the loop is working and the inArray check works.

Just not checking the checkboxes.
Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try:

```
for (id in savedShareIDs)
    $("input:checkbox[value="+savedShareIDs[id]+"]").attr("checked", "checked");
```

Comment: Hrm .. maybe the ajax call is doing something in the DOM that makes it unhappy.

Comment: $("input:checkbox[name=share_ids]").each(function()  
{  
 if ( $.inArray( $(this).val(), savedShareIDs) > -1 ) {  
  $(this).attr('checked',true);  
  $(this).attr('checked','checked');  
  $(this).data('checked','checked');  
  str = "Re-Checking ".concat($(this).val());  
  alert(str);  
 }  
});  
  
for (id in savedShareIDs) {  
 $("input:checkbox[value=" + id + "]").attr("checked", true);  
}

Comment: OK then, try printing something out on each iteration to ensure that `"input:checkbox[name=share_ids]"` actually does select some elements.

Comment: I added this to the add part: str = "Added to array ".concat($(this).val());
        alert(str); and it does pop up and say 'Added to array 81'

Comment: Then on the re-checking part I added: str = "Re-Checking ".concat($(this).val());
            alert(str); and it also pops up and says "Re-Checking 81". but still no checking happening.

Comment: for (id in savedShareIDs) {
 $("input:checkbox[value=" + savedShareIDs[id] + "]").attr("checked", "checked");
}

Comment: Thank you kindly to all, very much appreciated :-)

Comment: If your question has been solved you should pick an answer as the solution to close the question (welcome to Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
$(this).attr('checked',true)
```

to

```
$(this).attr('checked','checked')
```

Comment: Yer, I think you have to do this also.

Comment: that does not matter. Html doesnt check what property is set for checked

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your logic is correct.  but i have seen attr behave weirdly.

Try using $(this).data('checked','checked') instead